# Create user and immediately log them in

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, login

I built a component where a user fills in a form, and on submit it creates an account for them and tries to log them in immediately. The account creation works, but when it tries to log users in, I get the error `Invalid password`.

Here is the core the function:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

$user = new JUser;
$user->bind($data);
if (!$user->save()) {
    $this->setError($user->getError());
    return false;
}

$credentials = array(
    'username' => $user->username,
    'password' => $user->password_clear,
);
$app->login($credentials);
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing. When I do a `print_r` of all of the data I have, it's all correct. If I log in manually after getting the wrong password error, I log in correctly. I tried passing `$user->password` instead, but that didn't work either. If I modified index.php to do the exact same `$app->login`, it would log me in properly.

Clearly there's something I'm missing, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a wee module based on your code above and it worked ok. Here's my code for comparison. (I set URL params like `?newusr=fredc&newpwd=fredc`)

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$app = Factory::getApplication();   // equivalent of $app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;

if ($input->exists('newusr') && $input->exists('newpwd'))
{
    $usr = $input->get('newusr', 0, "STRING");  
    $pwd = $input->get('newpwd', 0, "STRING");

    $logged_on_user = JFactory::getUser();
    echo "Logged on user is " . $logged_on_user->username; 

    $user = new JUser();
    $data = array("name" => $usr, "username" => $usr, "email" => $usr . "@example.com", "password" => $pwd, "password_clear" => $pwd, "groups" => array("2"));
    $user->bind($data);
    if (!$user->save()) {
        $this->setError($user->getError());
        return false;
    }

    $credentials = array(
        'username' => $user->username,
        'password' => $user->password_clear,
    );
    $app->login($credentials);

    $logged_on_user = JFactory::getUser();
    echo "Logged on user is " . $logged_on_user->username; 
}
```

The second call to getUser() got the new user ok, and then the username was output ok.

Comment: My original code only had `password` being bound to user, because the bind event properly encrypted it for me. But, for whatever reason when I have both `password` and `password_clear` bound like your example, it just works. I don't understand why, but if it works I guess I'll just let it go for now.

Comment: I removed the password_clear element from the `$data` array and it still worked ok. So I think it's actually not needed.